# RabbitMQ client The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq.client

i m using RabbitMQ  client 5.2.0.

The requirements for the project i m working on are the following:

- Producer publishing high volume of data
- Scalable number of consumers and queues. Every consumer starting up will declare its own queues and it will subscribe to them
- when a consumerN is down, the other consumers have to catch that QueueN doesnt have consumer anymore consequently they have to unbind it and then delete it.

So basically each consumer per time will perform the following:

```
 uint count = _redisclient.ConsumerCount(queueName);
 if (count < 1)
 {
      _redisclient.QueueUnbind(queueName);
 }
```

Every time this last operation is performed i get the following exception:

`2021-09-14 19:29:22 [Error] Error while checking the queue: MT-SB-LP-007__LiveOddsChange_ConsistentHash_Inst_1_Process_4. Trying again on the next loop. Exception: Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=404, text='NOT_FOUND - no queue 'iis-sb-dev-3__LiveOddsChange_ConsistentHash_Inst_2_Process_8' in vhost '/'', classId=50, methodId=10    at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)`

after which the channel is in failure status and i cannot get any further information about the queues and the consumers.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the rabbitmq UI ? it is possible that you set autodelete on your queues and  they are deleted automatically by rabbitmq when the queuue hits 0 consumers. That is the default behaviour

Comment: i cannot use the autodelete for some race condition. The queues have to be unbound first programmatically... the autodelete doesn t work. Everything has to be done by code